# How can I get center of three 3Dpoint in potgreSQl?

Tags: postgis

How can I get center of three 3Dpoint in potgreSQl?
p1 (110 120 10)
p2 (150 90 8)
p3 (165 95 11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGIS can't do this (see [this enhancement request](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1783)).

The best PostGIS can do is only a 2D centroid (via [`ST_Centroid(geom)`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Centroid.html)):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT Z(110 120 10,150 90 8,165 95 11)'));

                st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POINT(141.666666666667 101.666666666667)
```

However, the algorithm for a centroid for points is fairly straightforward. Just average the coordinate values for all dimensions:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakePoint(avg(ST_X(geom)), avg(ST_Y(geom)), avg(ST_Z(geom))))
FROM (
  SELECT       1 AS id, 'POINT Z (110 120 10)'::geometry AS geom
  UNION SELECT 2 AS id, 'POINT Z (150 90 8)'::geometry AS geom
  UNION SELECT 3 AS id, 'POINT Z (165 95 11)'::geometry AS geom
) AS f;
                          st_astext
--------------------------------------------------------------
 POINT Z (141.666666666667 101.666666666667 9.66666666666667)
```

Other geometry types have more complicated algorithms.